# need to popviewcontroller but keep the current view hidden

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying the below code to hide the current view and pop to the previous viewcontroller's view but all i get with this code is a black screen on the view.. can't do anything on that...
relationship between the previous view controller and current view is "Modal Segue"

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.50 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.view.hidden = YES;

    } completion:nil];
}
```

I hope i'm clear in my question, if you have any question, please comment... thanks!

Comment: In the future, please try to format your code properly.

Comment: will do, thanks Richard

Comment: change `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` and read the UIViewController programming guide

Comment: would that dismiss the current view or "hide" it? i need to hide my current view so that the NSTimer running on the current view continues updating countdown timer... and i can come back to it anytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

popviewcontroller will destroy your topViewController and related UIView.
dismissModalViewController will destroy the navigationcontroller. so if you still want the navigationController on your screen you should look for some other solution. Consider a custom controller.